# how to implement vertical grid using ext js 5.1

Tags: extjs

How to implement vertical grid using ext js5.1 .the data coming from database and bind to grid.
i already implemented horizontal grid the grid is like below.

|Header 1|Header 2|Header 3|Header4|
|Data 1  |Data 2  |Data 3  |Data 4 |
|Data 1  |Data 2  |Data 3  |Data 4 |

but here i need vertical grid.i am trying past two days on wards.like below grid

header1| value1
header2| value2
header3| value3

any one please help to me.share any idea or related code to me.

Answer (score 0):

Would the propertygrid do what you need?
Check the docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.property.Grid', {
    title: 'Properties Grid',
    width: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    source: {
        "(name)": "My Object",
        "Created": Ext.Date.parse('10/15/2006', 'm/d/Y'),
        "Available": false,
        "Version": 0.01,
        "Description": "A test object"
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Guilherm,Thanks for responding to my post.this is not suitable for requirement.

Comment: Hi, it is hard to visualize what you want, can you at least draw it and submit the image here?

Comment: Hi Guliherm,  below i draw that grid